# How to keep a widget common in every tab of my android application?

Tags: android-widget, android-tabhost

How can I do this if I want it through XML file layout..

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could find a way to make the widgets share an ID? Don't think you could do that from the layout however (if at all).

[Is Android Widget ID persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086564/is-android-widget-id-persistent)